# Floating image across 2 of four columns

Tags: floats, columns

I wish to design a four-column poster, and I have an image that I would like to float across the middle two -- but not all four -- columns. The standard things I've been able to find involving figure* and/or multicols does not seem like it will work. Any advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In a poster you don't really need page breaking/floating at all, just do it by hand: put the image in one column, hide its width with

```
\makebox[0pt][l]{\includegraphics...}
```

so it will over-print the column to the right, then use `\vspace*{something}` to leave space in that column.